# hilios javascript countdown won't trigger the callback when finish

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple countdown on the same page. And this script was modified based on the single countdown. So I need it to trigger the alert each finish event on `<time>` tag. But I don't know why it's not alert at the end. Please help me out.

```js
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
  $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
    var format = '%H:%M:%S';
    $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
  }).on('finish.countdown', function() {
    alert('time up!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<time data-countdown="2021/07/28 10:28:40"></time>
<br />
<time data-countdown="2021/07/28 12:08:00"></time>
<br />
<time data-countdown="2021/07/29 00:00:00"></time>
```

You can try change the nearest time finish in the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ayonsd5h/2/

Comment: So what are you asking, to have some one write this for you? or do you have an actual issue that you need help with?

Comment: Where did you get the code sample from? Your not building it correctly. The data method takes more than 1 argument. I can tell you rn the first thing you need to fix is `finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');` also use `let` & `const` not `var`.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#jQuery-data-element-key-value

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The `alert` does not display for an unknown reason which I just can't explain. But replace it with `console.log` and you'll notice that everything works as expected.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette This is give me a headache since last night.

Comment: @JAY-DEV from the plugin example.